# Android MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DATE gives only date of video on galaxy S7

Tags: android, ffmpeg, metadata, video-processing

I am writing a code to get video creation date and time from metadata, i am using following code to get creation date

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(path_to_video);
String date = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DATE);
```

it works perfect on all devices except Samsung Galaxy S7, it returns only date in "YYYY MM DD" format, no time stamp i need both date and timestamp.

any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For printing metadata information of video FFMPEG is best option to use,

```
ffmpeg -i input_video -f ffmetadata metadata.txt
```

this command help me to get required info.

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issue. I handled both date formats as below:

```
//pass date fetched from MetadataRetriever class to below method.

    public static String formatMediaDate(String date){
            String formattedDate = "";
            try {
                Date inputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).parse(date);
                formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(inputDate);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.w(TAG, "error parsing date: ", e);
                try {
                    Date inputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd", Locale.getDefault()).parse(date);
                    formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(inputDate);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "error parsing date: ", ex);
                }
            }
            return formattedDate;
        }
```